# gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: eof

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install docker but my Ubuntu server can't connect for keys...

[image: output image]

The commands that I used are:

```
sudo su -
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no, i am using NAT.